# Angular 4 Date/DateRange Picker with stable implementation

Tags: angular, datepicker

I'm looking for a **Date/DateRange** plugin for **Angular 4**, but so far all of them seem to be lacking one feature or another:

1. **Reactive/Template Forms support**
2. **Easy Internationalization support**
3. Bootstrap CSS support
4. Clear Value button

Also, having the possibility to customize a list of quick picks for DateRange would be nice.

Is there any **stable** Date/DateRange plugin that covers all these features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can advise you the datepicker by ngx-bootstrap

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

It is availiable for Bootstrap 3 OR 4 wich make it very powerfull.

Comment: I used it myself and it's very useful

Answer (score 2):

This question is opinion based and too broad, and will be closed soon.

But in the meantime, see [this datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) made by the Angular team ;)

Comment: I hoped that adding a list of required features would not make this question opinion-based. Thank you for your suggestion, but I don't think that the material component could be easily integrated in a bootstrap themed app.

Comment: You can give them the style you want, don't stop on the style, otherwise you will never find your picker !

Comment: It does not have the range picker functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Actually as said by @trichetriche this question is opinion based,
but I also feel you can use PrimeNG component.
have a look here.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but we cannot integrate a full UI framework for just the calendar, because it would certainly conflict with out existing UI framework (ngx-bootstrap). I hoped to find an isolated plugin for date/daterange

Comment: This should not collide though : both libraries have distinct selectors, so you should be good.